# RegOpenKeyEx returns ERROR_SUCCESS but RegSetValueEx allways returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: c++

I am writing a function for setting key/value on registry. I have a problem:

I call RegOpenKeyEx() and it returns ERROR_SUCCESS and

I then call RegSetValueEx to set key/value but it returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

```
RegOpenKeyEx((HKEY)hive, branch.c_str(), NULL, ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY, &hkey_result);

RegSetValueEx(hkey_result, name.c_str(), 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)value.c_str(), 
    ((DWORD)wcslen(value.c_str()) + 1)* sizeof(wchar_t));
```

my function runs on Windows 7 and my program also sets UAC by embeding manifest with vs2010 IDE

The branch which i want to set key/value:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.html\UserChoice

i recognize that when i selected Permissions menu(use the Registry Editor (Regedt32.exe)) on UserChoice and it has "specical permisions" field with "Set Value" item checked on Deny column

hi all! can you help me?

Comment: Have you try to run vs2010 as an admin ? Have you all the rights on your computer ?

Comment: yes, I run the rights on my computer

Comment: Why are you trying to circumvent a user setting? This is exactly the sort of thing the specific security settings on the key are meant to prevent!

Comment: Because my app needs to do somethings with user setting. Do you have some solutions for me to resole it?

Comment: Let the user pick their user settings. That's why they are user settings.

Comment: Because i want to change some settings for running my progam.

Comment: The settings for running your program are not kept in that key. The settings for running your program are kept in `HKCR\<progid>`.

Comment: oh no! I want to change progid's value on above branch not on HKCR\<progid>

Answer (score 3):

Change `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY` to `KEY_SET_VALUE`.

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong access level on your RegOpenKeyEx call. ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY isn't one of the valid options, which are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The value of ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY corresponds to the same value as SYNCHRONIZE | STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED. These flags affect the top word of the flags, and the registry access rights live in the bottom word.

Try KEY_WRITE, or KEY_ALL_ACCESS if KEY_WRITE doesn't give you enough access.

Comment: i also try  KEY_WRITE, or KEY_ALL_ACCESS if KEY_WRITE as you suggested but RegOpenKeyEx always returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

Comment: OK. Leave those in place, as ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY won't give you any access at all. I assume you are running as a logged-in user, and not as a service?

Comment: I am running as addministrator.

Comment: OK. I asked because when a program runs as a service (configured to run as LocalSystem) the HKEY_CURRENT_USER part of the registry doesn't exist (it isn't loaded for you.) Not relevent here.

Comment: i am running as administrator and i also see the branch but i can not call RegSetValueEx to setting key/value as above question(ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)

Comment: I see that you have a "Set Value" deny permission on that key. I guess you'll have to open the key as KEY_ALL_ACCESS | ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY, edit the ACL to remove that DENY entry, set the value, then put the DENY entry back. Going about doing all of that, though, I expect is going to be long-winded. Good luck.

Comment: because some reasons i can not "edit the ACL to remove that DENY entry" as you suggested and i also try with KEY_ALL_ACCESS | ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY but RegOpenKeyEx returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

Comment: This might help with editing the ACL: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910528/how-to-change-the-acls-from-c> I note that the process requires the SE_SECURITY_NAME privilege to edit ACLS, and apparently Process Explorer can help you to determine whether your process has that.

Comment: Above ACLS solution only apply for file path, my problem is on registry. So I can not apply it for my situation. I can manually disable permission but it should not be a good solution.

Comment: That page outlines what you need to do to edit ACLs with an example relating to files. Go find out how to do the same for registry keys.

Answer (score 0):

## RegSetValueExA function

Sets the data and type of a specified value under a registry key.

### Parameters

#### hKey

A handle to an open registry key. The key must have been opened with the ***KEY_SET_VALUE*** access right. For more information, see [Registry Key Security and Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/SysInfo/registry-key-security-and-access-rights).

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvalueexa