# Change file Permissions of a specific user - Windows

Tags: windows, file, security, permissions

I want to give a specific User write/change access to a specific file.
I already have the SID of the user.
I tried to make use of the code specified here:
[how to change the ACLs from c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910528/how-to-change-the-acls-from-c)
but unfortunately it also strips the ALL permissions of other user groups.
Heres the current code I'm using:

```
PACL pACL = NULL;
EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea[1];
SecureZeroMemory(&ea, sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
ea[0].grfAccessPermissions = 0xFFFFFFFF;
ea[0].grfAccessMode = GRANT_ACCESS;
ea[0].grfInheritance = NO_INHERITANCE;
ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_USER;
ea[0].Trustee.ptstrName = (LPTSTR)pSid;

SetEntriesInAcl(1, ea, NULL, &pACL);

PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)LocalAlloc(LPTR, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH);

InitializeSecurityDescriptor(pSD, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);

SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(pSD, TRUE, pACL, FALSE);

SetFileSecurity(filename, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, pSD);

LocalFree(pACL);
LocalFree(pSD);
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: You need to read in the existing permissions, modify them as desired, then write them.  The SetEntriesInAcl function has an "old ACL" argument that should make this reasonably straightforward.