# Make file writable in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7-x64

On a Windows 7 machine, using c++, I am opening a file for writing in %ProgramData%\Company using:

```
        std::ofstream   s(fopen(f.AsANSI(), "wbc"));
```

However, this file is only writable by me (the user logged in when it is created). Is there a way to make it writable by all accounts on the PC?

I don't want to run the application as Administrator.

Comment: Check the permissions and ownership in windows.

Comment: What do you mean by all accounts? If another user logs in and run the program, do you allow that user to create and write to that file? Do you mean users who are not running the program?

Comment: Huh. That's new. Didn't know there was a `ofstream` constructor that eats a `FILE`. Is this an extention? What compiler is this? On topic, C++ has no understanding of file permissions or that they even exist. You will have to use an OS call, I'm afraid.

Comment: Para-duplicate: [how to change the ACLs from c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910528/how-to-change-the-acls-from-c) You should also be able to set the permissions [on creation with `CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I'm using Visual C++ 2017. I sort of guessed I would need to use OS calls to make this work. I have looked at the ACLs solution, and am working through it. It is a huge pig, and really hard to decipher. I was sort of of hoping there was a simple solution.
The constructor is in code I am maintaining (I didn't write it), so I didn't think much about the fact it was an ofstream from a FILE *. It si a bit odd, isn't it?

Comment: Rather than messing with ACLs why not save the file somewhere else?

Comment: For historic reasons, moving the file is not an option.

Comment: What about fixing the acl when you create the directory? In the install program.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to code this in C++ (and who would) then you can use the [icacls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls) command line utility to do the dirty work for you.  The command you want is something like:

```
icacls <filename> /grant *S-1-1-0:rwm
```

HOWEVER: you still need Administrator rights to do this.  I don't think there's any way round that.